# How do I make UI elements fill the entire Android Screen

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to add a bar similar to the "Today" bar here, but I cannot figure out how to force the width to match the screen. I am just using a simple textview (if there is a better way.. that's awesome, please tell it to me, but i cant find anything for it)

[image]

Here is what is happening with match_parent or fill_parent I recolored the textview to show the margins (that I dont want)

[image]

Comment: why not `match_parent` for the width XML attribute?

Comment: match_parent has about a 20dp padding on each side. It doesnt actually go the entire way to the edge of the screen (TextView is nested within a RelativeLayout if that helps)

Comment: In your final layout, is the shopping list textview a different color? because if you match the textview color with the color of everything then you would be okay?

Comment: I would like it to be a different color (not the color i have shown, but different) I would like it to be a sort of subtitle for the page. Also, more importantly actually, I would like to know how to push ui elements to the edge of the screen

Comment: Right okay, but without removing the padding that's already there correct? You could programmatically modify the padding for the textview but the textview has no padding, so you would have to modify the padding for the parent layout. Try that but I think it would take it off the whole screen.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't remove the padding off the parent relative layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

match_parent should fill the entire screen. 
Check your parent activity layout or your fragment layout and you should find your margins there.

BTW,  if you have a list of items like the one in the picture and you want it to have sections (like 'today', 'yesterday', etc) you should probably use recyclerview with headers instead of text view. Check this library for this, it's pretty easy:
https://github.com/cymcsg/UltimateRecyclerView